# Powershell Office365 licensing steps clarification

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm trying to understand why certain commands are failing when trying to provision unlicensed test users.

In particular,

```
$1 = "test-sp2@mycompany.org"
$a = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $1
$test = New-MsolLicenseOptions -AccountSkuId "mycompany:STANDARDWOFFPACK_FACULTY" -DisabledPlans @("PROJECTWORKMANAGEMENT","SWAY","INTUNE_O365","YAMMER_EDU","SHAREPOINTWAC_EDU","SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE_EDU")

Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $1 -LicenseOptions $test

Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $1 -AddLicenses "mycompany:STANDARDWOFFPACK_FACULTY" -LicenseOptions $test2
```

The latter 2 are failing with `Set-MsolUserLicense : Unable to assign this license because the license options are invalid.`

Does a user need a full license installed with "all" products installed to then be able to disabled ones you don't want them to have? Seems hokey to me? What am I missing?

This seems to work fine on licensed users only?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that the test user didn't have a UsageLocation set. Once I set it to US, all the above commands were successful.